# how to solve "gradle failed resolve com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:+"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I install new version of Android Studio"2.1.0.9". Now when sync gradle error message in this:

```
gradle failed resolve com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:+
```

I used any version of image cropper but still this message there is.
gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.0.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Apis:Google Apis:23'
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
defaultConfig {  
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
}
```

Comment: call `compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.0.+'` then `Clean and rebuild` your project

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Suggestion will work.

Comment: @jaydroider  lets see what happen

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya this error still is:
     Required by:
         MyProject:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.0.+.
 > Failed to list versions for com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper.
  > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused
      > Could not resolve com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.0.+.
         > Failed to list versions for com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper.

Comment: OKAY @Tom SHOW YOUR `BUILD.GRADLE`

Comment: @Tom show your total build.gradle (Add this in your question section)

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I posted it.

Comment: @Tom try this lib dependencies {
   
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.0.0'
   
}

Comment: Guys! I'm also facing the same problem. It just suddenly gave me an error. Any solutions on this?

Comment: I use Hotspot Shield when gradle is syncing and my problem solved.

Answer (score 6):

you should to replace the dependency by this

```
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.1'
```

it'works for me

Answer (score 5):

Following steps worked for me after searching and finding solutions from various souces.

**Step1:**
Add the following in **AndroindManifest.xml** at **android/app/src/main**

```
<activity
   android:name="com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity"
   android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat">
</activity>
```

**Step2:**
Add the below lines of code to **/android/build.gradle**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
       .................................
        //noinspection JcenterRepositoryObsolete
        jcenter() {
            content {
                includeModule("com.theartofdev.edmodo", "android-image-cropper")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step3:**  Add the below line inside **dependencies {}** node in **andoid/app/build.gradle**

```
implementation "com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0"
```

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem all you have to do is visit this link

https://bintray.com/package/files/arthurhub/maven/Android-Image-Cropper?order=asc&sort=name&basePath=com%2Ftheartofdev%2Fedmodo%2Fandroid-image-cropper&tab=files

scroll to the bottom and replace your dependency with the latest version.

example: if previously your dependency is

```
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
```

then replace it with (at the time of posting the answer the latest is **2.4.7**)

```
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'
```

Answer (score 0):

when use mavenCentral inside of jcenter you get this issue , dont change jcenter

Answer (score 0):

Replace Library with

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.1'
```

Avoid using '+' sign in last.

Answer (score 0):

```
change version don't use + if you use android studio bumblebee, go to setting.gradle, and add jcenter() :

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

implementation("com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.3.3")

you can used this place of
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'

Answer (score 0):

If someone still using it I fixed it using this

```
implementation "com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0"
```

Add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
        android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
```

In `settings.gradle`

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
   repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
   repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
       jcenter()//Add this but this will give you deprecated API
   }
}
```

Add this in `gradle.properties`

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

In settings.Gradle use jcenter() instead of mavenCentral().
And use newer version of CropImage.

Answer (score 0):

Just update dependency version which is mention below:

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
```